# Differentiability Of Functions

Tags: calculus

Why the condition of differentiability is always given on an open interval not on a closed interval, even if we consider the function $$f(x)=|x|$$ defined for all $x>0$, this function is derivable at all the points $[0, ∞)$

Comment: Did you mean all $x \geq 0$?

Comment: You can define a [one-sided derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability).  However, it is a weaker condition than differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the example taking the interval $[0,\infty)$ makes not much sense. Open intervals (neighborhoods) are key.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0+}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$ goes to $1$ if $x=0$.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0-}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$ goes to $-1$ if $x=0$.

So at $x=0$ the function $x\mapsto|x|$ is not differentiable.